# Use regex to replace all possible substrings made from newline characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm writing a regex to remove excessive numbers of line breaks from a piece of text and replace them with single line break, when the newline character `\n` can occur in any number of concatentations with itself and the space character. However, I can't quite get it right. Here's one text that's not working:

`text` = 'This is a text \n \n\n for illustration. \n \n  \n\n  It is  most annoying:  \n why?'

Here's my code:

```
import re

clean = re.compile(
            "( *(?:\\n.?)+) +").sub(r"\n", text)
```

However, I keep getting a line break in the third line I don't want:

```
>>>print(clean)


"This is a text
for illustration.

It is  most annoying:
why?
```

Can anyone suggest a better regex? Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/GIni5N/1) help? What is your expected result?

Comment: This is very close, thank you very much. The only issue is that there's a space before the first word "why?" on the last line. How might I specify that this be removed?

Comment: But there is no match as there is only 1 newline. Use `[^\S\n]*(?:\n[^\S\n]*)+` then, see https://regex101.com/r/GIni5N/4

Comment: This is ideal, thank you! Could I ask you to explain what `[^\S\n]` exactly? I can follow the rest.

Comment: It is a negated character class that matches any char but a non-whitespace char and LF char. It is the same as `(?!\n)\s`, a whitespace matching pattern with LF subtracted from it.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex replacement in `MULTILINE` mode:

```
\s+$\s*
```

This regex matches 1+ whitespaces (including newline) followed by end anchor and optional 0 or more whitespaces. We just need to replace it using a single newline.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GIni5N/5)

**Code:**

```
>>> regex = r"\s+$\s*"
>>> s = ("This is a text \n"
...     " \n\n"
...     " for illustration. \n"
...     " \n"
...     " \n\n"
...     " It is most annoying: \n"
...     " why?")
>>> print ( re.sub(regex, '\n', s, 0, re.M) )

This is a text
for illustration.
It is most annoying:
why?
```

Comment: This is very useful, thanks. Can I ask what the `re.M` does here?

Comment: `re.M` is same as `re.MULTILINE` which makes `$` match position before each line break in input string.

Comment: I believe `\s*$\s*` and `\s*\r?\n\s*` are OK too.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks for your comment. I believe `\s+$\s*` covers all the cases and avoid matching an unnecessary match of 2 consecutive lines with no leading+trailing spaces. Please let me know if you find any case that is not covered with `\s+$\s*`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'[^\S\n]*(?:\n[^\S\n]*)+', '\n', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GIni5N/4/). Details:

- `[^\S\n]*`  - 0+ whitespaces other than line feed
- `(?:\n[^\S\n]*)+`  - 1 or more occurrences of a line feed char followed with 0 or more whitespaces other than line feed.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kIZnT9):

```
import re
text = 'This is a text \n \n\n for illustration. \n \n \n\n It is most annoying: \n why?'
print ( re.sub(r'[^\S\n]*(?:\n[^\S\n]*)+', '\n', text) )
```

Output:

```
This is a text
for illustration.
It is most annoying:
why?
```